# Bootstrap 3 responsive drop down nav links not working

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my link: http://www.websouthend.co.uk/jc/

I am having issues with my drop down menu.

Under the galleries link there is a drop down, which is dropping down and displaying fine in Firefox, a little funky in chrome but can be fixed with css.

My issue is the links aren't actually directing to the pages... The markup looks ok the anchor tags are surrounding the text and formatted correctly, so I can't for the life of me figure our what's missing.

Comment: I have eliminated the data-toggle from the sub items but am still experiencing the same problem. Links won't open when clicked. The correct url is generated on hover but something is preventing them from firing.

Comment: I removed the data toggle from the sub menus and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub menu (drop down menu) anchors have a `data-toggle="dropdown"` i expect this prevent the link from opening. Javascript try to open a new dropdown and the default click behavior stops.
Also see: https://github.com/bassjobsen/jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme/issues/20